# Get context with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to get context of a search string, my first approach is this regex:

```
!\.(.{20,})' . $string . '(.{20,})\.!
```

That works for `The fox is jumping in the garden` in

> Yes. The bird is flying in the wind. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.

but not for

> The bird is flying in the wind. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.

because the first dot is missing. So I would need something that is a dot OR the beginning of the string.

But then I would still have a problem with

> The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.

or even with

> Yes. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.

I want to have as much content as possible (to be honest, 60 chars would be better than 20). But I also want it to work when there is no more chars. How can I achieve that?

https://regex101.com/r/P3sFTw/1

edit: sorry, I should have said, that I always want to have full sentences as context. So to say: left and right minimum 60 chars (if exists), but don't cut sentences and extend the 60 chars to the next dot (or start of string).

Comment: Could you show what you want for each sentences?

Answer (score 0):

```
$testArray = [
    'Yes. The bird is flying in the wind. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.' => '...The fox is jumping in the <strong>garden</strong> when he is happy. But that...',
    'The bird is flying in the wind. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.'      => '...The fox is jumping in the <strong>garden</strong> when he is happy. But that...',
    'The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.'                                      => '...is jumping in the <strong>garden</strong> when he is happy...',
    'Yes. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story.'                                 => '...fox is jumping in the <strong>garden</strong> when he is happy...',
    'Yes. The fox is jumping in the garden when he is happy. But that is not the whole story of the garden story.'             => '...The fox is jumping in the <strong>garden</strong> when he is happy. But...',
];
```

--> here some test results :) via ... "extractText()"

```
$searchString = 'garden';
foreach ($testArray as $testString => $testExpected) {
  $stringy = S::create($testString);
  $result = $stringy->extractText($searchString)
                    ->replace($searchString, '<strong>' . $searchString . '</strong>')
                    ->toString();
  self::assertSame($testExpected, $result, 'tested: ' . $testString);
}
```

--> https://github.com/voku/Stringy/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After the clarification of the question, here is hopefully what you're after (I'm sure you can adapt it to use a variable instead):

```
[^.]*.{0,20}The fox is jumping in the garden.{0,20}.*?(?:\.|$)
```

Link to example:

https://regex101.com/r/P3sFTw/5

**ORIGINAL:** You can use the following Regex:

```
(.{0,20})The fox is jumping in the garden(.{0,20})
```

Link to example:

https://regex101.com/r/P3sFTw/3

Comment: I updated my explanation because i didn't point out enough, that I want full sentences on both sides

Comment: Added a new version that should (hopefully) fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> So I would need something that is a dot OR the beginning of the string.

This one does the job:

```
!(?:^|\.)(.{20,})' . $string . '(.{20,})\.!
```

Comment: @Asara:Well, what is the full problem? Edit your question and add test cases with expected result.